# Datastax Cassandra PHP Driver : How to know CQL INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE are Successful

Tags: cassandra, datastax-php-driver

I am using Datastax php-driver to run CQL on my cassandra. I use INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE operation.

Below is sample code I run for insert

```
        $cluster = Cassandra::cluster()
                ->withContactPoints('54.XX.XX.XX', '54.XX.XX.XX','54.XX.XX.XX')
                ->withDefaultConsistency(4)
                ->build();

        $session = $cluster->connect('Sample_Key_Space');
        $statement = new Cassandra\SimpleStatement('insert_query');
        $result = $session->execute($statement);
```

My Question is, How to know the insert(or update,delete) is successful. I have read Datastax document and know that **$session->execute** return **Cassandra\Rows**, using this Rows object "**How to judge my CQL is successful or Failed?**".

Any help or inputs are much appreciated...

UPDATES:

Based on the answer, the working code samples

```
try {
$cluster = Cassandra::cluster()
            ->withContactPoints('54.XX.XX.XX')
            ->withDefaultConsistency(4)
            ->build();

    $session = $cluster->connect('school');

    $statement = new Cassandra\SimpleStatement("UPDATE1 activities SET activity_by = 'nagarajan' WHERE master_id = 12 AND activity_type='Hello' AND activity_id=10");
$result = $session->execute($statement);
return true;
} catch (Cassandra\Exception $e $e) {
    return 'failed';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surround the execute method with `try catch`.
If the query fails execute method throws exception which you can check in your application.

For more details visit
[Session.Execute](http://datastax.github.io/php-driver/api/Cassandra/interface.Session/#method.execute) .

Comment: I tried it like try { ....execution..... }  catch (Exception $e){ .....  error result .......}. When I execute wrong sql statement  for say UPDATE123 SET ... instead of UPDATE SET ... , the catch statement not working? What I am doing wrong?.. Please see my updates in my question, I given entire code

Comment: can you try `catch (Cassandra::Exception $e)`

Comment: I finally Got it by giving catch (Cassandra\Exception $e)